# Linked List - Data Structure

Tags: data-structures

What is the output of following function when head node of following linked list is passed as input?
1->2->3->4->5

```
def fun(head):
    if(head==None):
        return
    if head.get_next().get_next()!= None:
        print(head.get_data()," ", end='')
        fun(head.get_next())
    print(head.get_data()," ",end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a call to `print(head.get_data()," ",end='')` before AND after the recursive call to `fun(head.get_next())`. The first print is on line 5 in the `if` block, and the second print is on line 7 outside of the `if` block.

When on the first node, this means the function will first print `1`, then perform the recursive calls, then print `1` again. So we should expect the output to be:

```
1 [output of recursive call on second node] 1
```

When on the second and third nodes, the same thing happens; so the output of the call on the second node is:

```
2 [output of recursive call on third node] 2
```

Therefore we should expect the output on first node to be:

```
1 2 [output of recursive call on third node] 2 1
```

Same thing happens on node 3, so we should expect the output on first node to be:

```
1 2 3 [output of recursive call on fourth node] 3 2 1
```

During the call on the fourth node, the `if` block is not executed, because `head.get_next().get_next()` is `None`. Hence the first print and the recursive call don't happen. So we're left with just one print, which means the output of the call on fourth node is just `4`.

Finally, putting all that together we can see that the output of the call on first node is:

```
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

A nice way to think of what is happening is to imagine a "call stack". The call to `fun` on the first node results in:

1. print 1 { TO DO }
2. recursive call on second node { TO DO }
3. print 1 { TO DO }

When the recursive call is performed, execution of the function is interrupted while waiting for the end of the recursive call. Hence the new call is "stacked" on top of the previous, unfinished, call. So the first layer of the stack is now:

1. print 1 { DONE}
2. recursive call on second node { IN PROGRESS }
3. print 1 { TO DO }

And a new layer is put on top:

1. print 2 { TO DO}
2. recursive call on third node { TO DO }
3. print 2 { TO DO }

As recursive calls progress, new layers are put on the call stack, with the first print becoming {DONE} and the last print remaining {TODO}.

Once the call on the first node terminates, it is unstacked. So the call on the third node is on top again; its remaining `print 3` instruction is executed, then it is unstacked; now the call on the second node is on top again; its remaining `print 2` is executed, then it is unstacked; the call to first node is on top again; its remaining `print 1` is executed; finally, the call on the first node is unstacked, and the call stack is empty, meaning that execution of the whole program is finished.